# My Function returns 'None' rather than what I want, even though I provided return

Tags: python, function, nonetype

The english file on the function's parameter is already running. I tried to check if the words I have are triad words by comparing them against the cleaned dictionary file, but it always returns NONE for every print statement. what am i missing here? Triad words are English words for which the two smaller strings you make by extracting alternating letters both form valid words.

```
def is_triad_word(word, english):
    """Return whether a word is a triad word."""
    for wrd in word.split():
        if wrd[::2] in english:
            return True
        else:
            return False
        if wrd[1::2] in english:
            return True
        else:
            return False

print(
   is_triad_phrase("learned theorem",english), # => True
   is_triad_phrase("studied theories",english), # => False
   is_triad_phrase("wooded agrarians", english), # => False 
   is_triad_phrase("forrested farmers", english), # => False
   is_triad_phrase("schooled oriole", english), # => True
   is_triad_phrase("educated small bird",english), # => False
   is_triad_phrase("a",english), # => False
   is_triad_phrase("",english), # => False
)
```

Result : None None None None None None None None

different syntax, same concept, with same results

```
def is_triad_word(word, english):
    """Return whether a word is a triad word."""
    wrd_list = []
    for wrd in word:
        word_list += wrd.split()
        if wrd[::2] in english:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Comment: It is the dictionary file assigned to ' english 'after cleaning

Comment: There are **many** things wrong with this code. The first problem that stands out is that the function that you say isn't working is called `is_triad_word`, but the code you use to test it tries to call `is_triad_phrase` instead. The second problem is that you can only return once from a given call to a function; the logic inside the `for` loop makes no sense, as no word past the first can ever be considered. The third problem is that `''.split()` returns an empty list, so the loop does not run and nothing is returned.

Comment: Please read [ask] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592 and [mre]. Before posting, make sure (by **trying it yourself**) that someone else can **copy and paste** your code **without changing anything** and **directly** see the **exact** problem you describe (and not any other problem). Make your best attempt to locate the problem and then show **only** the code needed to reproduce it. Try to look for existing questions and avoid posting a duplicate.

Comment: My advice is to try writing a function first that actually does handle a **single** word (i.e. **does not** contain code to loop over words, or split a phrase into words), and **make sure it works**. Only then, write code to handle a phrase, by **using** the first function. Try to look for existing questions about that logic - stuff like "how can I apply a function to every element in a list?" or "how can I make sure that every element in a list meets a condition?".

Comment: "The english file on the function's parameter is already running" This is not understandable English, and does not help anyone else to test the code.

Comment: What's the purpose of `wrd_list` in the second version? You never use it.

Comment: The second version is looping over the characters in `word`, not the words.

Comment: You're calling `is_triad_phrase` inside 
the print statement but have shown us definitions of `is_triad_word`. Have you accidentally copied from different versions of your code or might there be another function defined as `is_triad_phrase` which could return `None`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to combine the test of the odd and even characters using `and`, not separate return statements, since the function ends at the first `return` statement that's executed.

If you want to test all the words to see if they're triad words, use the `all()` function.

```
def is_triad_word(words, english):
    return all(word[::2] in english and word[1::2] in english for word in words.split())
```

You might want to break this up into two functions (which I think you might have done, because of the different function names in the snippet.

```
def is_triad_word(word, english):
    return word[::2] in english and word[1::2] in english

def is_triad_phrase(words, english):
    return all(is_triad_word(word) for word in words.split())
```